# How to get image dimensions in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to check the dimensions of the image when the user selects the file to upload with `<input type = "file">`

So far I've done this code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg"  ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" ng-model='company.logo'>
```

**AngularJS**

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL($files[0]);      
  reader.onload = function(e) {         
      $scope.imgpath = new Image();
      $scope.imgpath = e.target.result;
      console.log($scope.imgpath.width, $scope.imgpath.height);  
  }
```

In the console, the height and width of the selected image is being shown as 0,0.

I've referred the answer(which is not accepted but upvoted 5 times) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496567/how-to-get-the-image-dimension-with-angular-file-upload).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I tried this code and it worked:

```
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                $scope.imgpath = new Image();
                fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                    $scope.imgpath.src = event.target.result;
                    $scope.imgpath.onload = function(){
                        console.log(this.width, this.height);
                    };
                };
```

Source : [This code from CodePen](https://codepen.io/Zveg/pen/WbXNeQ)

Answer (score -1):

```
$scope.imgpath = e.target.result;
```

should be

```
$scope.imgpath.src = e.target.result;
```

Comment: Yes, it should be but still, I'm not able to get the dimensions.