# AngularJS get element inside ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the follwing AngularJS code:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="m in n.multimedia" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}">
    <img class="effect-image" ng-src="{{getResizedImage(m.path)}}" alt="{{m.name}}" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```

the Controller has a function "getResizedImage" which, from the path of the image, should ask the server to send the image scaled for the actual size of the HTML element, so I need, somehow, access the img element width and height in "getResizedImage". How is that possible?

If I got the element inside "getResizedImage" I could do something like $(element).width() and $(element).height() for discover the actual size using JQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I was thinking to get the element for Jquery usage like $(element).width() and $(element).height())

Comment: I think this may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45605603/1583507